# "Normal" (split) Master detail page in xamarin on phone

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail

From Android I know Master detail flow which allows you to have this side by side master detail activity on bigger devices while having two separate activities on a smaller device. As shown [on this page](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial) in the figures 23-1 and 23-2.

Now I am implementing in Xamarin for cross platform development and I would like to recreate this behavior as I really like it. The MasterDetailPage as it is called in Xamarin works correctly on a tablet, however on a small phone it shows a side menu for the master list view instead of a separate page. (this side menu is triggered by the burger menu button) Since my master page should already show more information than just a title in the list view, I would prefer it to be the normal android master detail flow with two pages. Is there a way to do this with Xamarin where I don't have to code it completely from scratch?

I haven't found any answers to it, but maybe that is because I search a bit wrong. I just don't know how to describe it better than as the "normal master detail" on android. But that doesn't give me useful results. Thanks for any help, also references to where I can find this.

Edit: Thanks to SushiHangover I now know that this behavior is called Split by xamarin. However they do not allow it on phones. Is there a workaround?

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/adaptive-mobile-designs-with-flexlayout/

Comment: @SushiHangover Not sure how this helps. The only thing the article mentions about tablets is the percentage width but I can do that with Grid in Xamarin forms already. But nothing about master detail flow.

Comment: Wrong blog link.. https://blog.xamarin.com/implement-drawer-split-ui-xamarin-forms-masterdetailpage/

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks. Now I know that it is called "Split" and "Popover" behavior and I can search better. I was already hoping it would be solved, but "Xamarin.Forms always chooses popover behavior on a phone. Your setting for MasterBehavior and the screen orientation are not used in the calculation."... Stupid xamarin :D

Comment: I'll have to look at some of the code I've done later as I have done "split view" styles on phones, but can not remember if it was via custom renderers, mod'ed Forms source, ....